# Creating a Javascript Slideshow Using Button ID

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow, dreamweaver, imagebutton

I'm trying to create a slideshow with Javascript using this HTML. Thanks

```
    <body>  
    <button id="next"> <img src ="buttons/next.png"/> </button>

    <button id="back"> <img src = "buttons/back.png"/> </button>

    <div class="container">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
    <img src="agctype.jpg"/></div>

    <div>
    <img src="America.jpg"/></div>

    <div>
    <img src= "sbjlogo2.jpg"/></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: umm, it seam that you know nothing about js and html. I suggest you find a existing jQuery slideshow plug-in in google. It can save you a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks and I know that's how it appears. This is my first post and my first attempt at creating a slideshow from scratch that has buttons, using JS. The thing is....this HTML, as ugly as it appears, actually creates a page that is laid out how I want it. I didn't post CSS or the existing JS that I'm using just because...I usually create slideshows in Flash, so creating one using JS would be awesome. My apologies for the choppy code.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout codepen.io , I did a search for simple slide show. This one looks good for beginners http://codepen.io/jonny_roller/pen/MaNGwV

**HTML**

```
A Simple Slideshow

<div class="slideshow" onmouseover="showControls(this)" onmouseout="hideControls(this)">
  <div class="controls hidden">
    <a id="previous" href="" onclick="return slideshowPrevious()">&#8249;</a>
    <a id="play" class="hidden" href="" onclick="return slideshowPlay()">&#8882;</a>
    <a id="pause" href="" onclick="return slideshowPause()">||</a>
    <a id="next" href="" onclick="return slideshowNext()">&#8250;</a>
  </div>

<div id="slide1" class="slide display" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/)">
  <span>Cricket: Some text goes here</span>
</div>

<div id="slide2" class="slide" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2/)">
  <span>Surfing: Some more text appears here</span>
</div>

<div id="slide3" class="slide" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3/)">
  <span>Cycling: This is the text for the final slide... it's a bit longer</span>
</div>

</div>

Some text at the bottom
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.slideshow {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

.controls a {
  z-index: 10;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#previous {
  top: 80px;
  left: 5px;
}

#next {
  top: 80px;
  right: 5px;
}

#play, #pause {
  top: 80px;
  left: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

#pause {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 34px;
}

#play {
  line-height: 34px;
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 50%;  /* 200/400 */

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;

  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;

  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}

.slide span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}

.display {
  opacity: 1;
}

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
```

**JS**

```
var delay=3;

var slides=document.getElementsByClassName('slide').length;
var current=1;
var timer = setTimeout(nextSlide, delay*1000);

function nextSlide() {
  var next = (current == slides ? 1 : current + 1);
  $('slide' + current).classList.remove('display');
  $('slide' + next).classList.add('display');

  current = next;
  timer = setTimeout(nextSlide, delay*1000);
}

function slideshowNext() {
  slideshowPause();

  var next = (current == slides ? 1 : current + 1);
  $('slide' + current).classList.remove('display');
  $('slide' + next).classList.add('display');
  current = next;

  return(false);
}

function slideshowPrevious() {
  slideshowPause();

  var prev = (current == 1 ? slides : current - 1);
  $('slide' + current).classList.remove('display');
  $('slide' + prev).classList.add('display');
  current = prev;

  return(false);
}

function slideshowPause() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = false;
  $('pause').classList.add('hidden');
  $('play').classList.remove('hidden');
  return(false);
}

function slideshowPlay() {
  $('pause').classList.remove('hidden');
  $('play').classList.add('hidden');
  nextSlide();
  return(false);
}

function showControls(slideshow) {
  slideshow.children[0].classList.remove('hidden');
}

function hideControls(slideshow) {
  if (timer) {
    slideshow.children[0].classList.add('hidden');
  }
}

function $(id) {
  return(document.getElementById(id));
}
```

Comment: Did this end up working. If so would you accept my answer?